# How to set all properties to null without boilperplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I must to set all my properties from `object A` to null, but i don't want do it like this:

```
getA().getB().getC().setD(null);
getA().getB().getC().setE(null);
getA().getB().getC().setF(null);
getA().getB().getC().setG(null);
getA().getB().getC().setH(null);
```

I have a many properties that i must set on null and i dont want do it like above because i have a big boilerplate.

Is there any way to do it better(without boilerplae code)?

thanks for any help

Comment: Do not initialize the fileds in class `C`. Uninitialized fields are initialized with `null` by default.

Comment: but `C` have methods that i use in different places and i can't set it on null

Comment: It's either one or the other. Either set its fields to default values that are `!= null` and initialize all field with `null` when needed or have it the other way around.

Comment: You could write a script to generate your code.

Answer (score 0):

First you might not initialize fields resulting them to be null.

```java
getA().getB().setC(new C()); // Empty by default
```

However if your fields already have a value you might add a `public void reset();` method which will reset those fields and call it with

```java
getA().getB().getC().reset();
```

*Edit 1 : `reset()` function example*

```java
public void reset() {
    this.D = null;
    this.E = null;
    // keep F
    this.G = null;
}
```

Comment: any body to `reset()` method is needed?

Comment: you need to set expected properties to `null` ofc. Without more context about C class we can't understand you problem... we don't even get constructors or constraints. To set fields to null, you should set fields to null. Using a `reset()` mehtod seems cleaner, but maybe your use-case might be designed a better way ... We need details to investigate, if you don't provide them, we can't help you more.

Comment: and I can't set to null, one of the property, how to skip this property?

Comment: Just don't set it to null in your `reset()` method

Comment: hmmm but your solving is another boilerplate

Comment: because i need to use another `getA()...` for all properties

Comment: Why don't you just set B property to null in A. `getA().setB(null)`
This implementation isn't a boilerplate as you might call multiple time `reset()` without reseting every fields one by one.

Comment: Provide A,B,C classes if you want a more detailled answer